# Vertical position of star in full vs mobile chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web, chat-stars

My [chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40691581#40691581) (which actually is an image) has been stared by someone. In mobile chat it looks like this:

> [image: Mobile]

But for full web chat, a star is shown at the bottom of the message:

> [image: Full web chat]

Is it possible to make them consistent?

The transcript draws a star at the bottom for both: mobile and full web versions.

Comment: Actually, that looks like its only a thing for oneboxen - https://i.stack.imgur.com/q28o8.png seems ok for normal text. Screenshot taken with Vivaldi - which uses the mobile view for the "web snippet" sidebar. Pretty handy for side by side screenshots :)